# save R image plot via org.rosuda.jri.rengine

Tags: r, plot, jri

I use org.rosuda.jri lib to run an R script that implements the ordinary kirging algorithm  via java. I use ubuntu 13.04 and the version 1.7-3 of REngine While all the results are perfectly produced **BUT i can not create the plots and store them.**

while the following lines are perfectly executed in R console

```
png('/home/panisis/Desktop/plots/tralala.png');
spplot(df);
dev.off();
```

These ones are ignored

```
re.eval("png('/home/panisis/Desktop/plots/tralala.png');"); 
re.eval("spplot(df);");
re.eval("dev.off();");
```

What i am missing???
Thanks for the dedicated time. :-)

Comment: Hi! i just found the answer myself. i put it here for next users. i had to assign the plot to a temporary variable (like temp <- spplot()) and then use print(temp) to save it as png file

for example

`temp <- spplot()
png(filename="pathToFile")
print(temp)
dev.off()`

Comment: please post it as an answer, so people will know its answerd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just found the answer myself. i put it here for next users. i had to assign the plot to a temporary variable (like temp <- spplot()) and then use print(temp) to save it as png file for example temp <- spplot() png(filename="pathToFile") print(temp) dev.off()